# hotcakes custom payment provider

Tags: e-commerce, dotnetnuke

I just tried to set up a new payment method, following the example here: https://hotcakescommerce.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204725899-Custom-Payment-Method-Example

However, I'm missing some next steps.
So it seems the 1st thing is redirect the customer to the payment provider in the ProcessCheckout method.

And it also seems that when the user is redirected back I can add some code to the Checkoutcontroller class, to do some updates on the order.

However, at some point, the payment provider will also do a server-to-server call, before the customer is sent back to the store website.
Is there some way/some place I can process that response too?

I also need to send the return url to the payment provider. Is there a good way to construct this url ?

Comment: Just found out that you can use:
 HccUrlBuilder.RouteHccUrl(HccRoute.ThirdPartyPayment).
So that seems to be the url to use as the return url.

Comment: However, I need some way for the payment provider to set the status of the order. And I don't think you can use: var model = new CheckoutViewModel {CurrentOrder = HccApp.OrderServices.CurrentShoppingCart()};

Since this relies on cookies or sessions or whatever.
So how can I get the correct order to update???